# Send email with Laravel using bluehost

Tags: laravel, email, sendmail, bluehost

I want to send email from Laravel application and everything have done successfully on mailtrap but when I enter my mail and all mail configuration on .env file there is no error but the mail hasn't sent (Bluehost)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ec@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

please 
any help

Comment: Make sure that you have used the correct mail configuration settings including the encryption and port. Try with SSL encryption.

Comment: now I replace the  ENCRYPTION to SSL and the error is gone and everything was done successfully but the mail still has not sent

Comment: Check your spam folder.

Comment: I checked it and nothing there

Answer (score 2):

If your emails are working fine with Mailtrap/Mailgun. And lets say you are using the correct SMTP credentials for Bluehost but its not working without giving any error or logs.

then try to add this line under SMTP configuration in config/mail.php file

```
'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
```

and then add this to your .env file

```
MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score -1):

`mail.domain.com` and `@domain.com` are just examples, you need to replace these with the details of your own email service.

Comment: yes for sure I had replaced it I just put it as example

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and its worked for me

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=26
MAIL_USERNAME='example@domain.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD= email account password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```